# "Permission denied: connect" trying to ssh to an Amazon instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions

Why would I get a "Permission denied: connect" while trying to ssh to an amazon instance? I'm using the same key pair that works with other instances in my account. Only this new instance I just created doesn't allow me to ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has occurred only once more till now - when I attached a 64-bit volume to a 32-bit instance.

And earlier I am guessing the instance just got corrupted when I tried to shutdown tomcat manually (which btw you shouldn't do beanstalk)

Recreating the instance in both the cases sorted the issue (though it didn't let me recover the existing instances)

For want of any better answer, I will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check **/var/log/secure**, it'll usually give you an idea of what could be the problem with SSH.

Were both instances created with the same keypair?

You're trying to ssh as ec2-user?

Comment: same keypair. user was ec2-user. i deleted the instance and created a new one and was able to login with the same keypair. will check /var/log/secure the next time it happens. Thanks.